# Ordinary SQLite vs FTS3 Tables

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

I have some data that is already organized in an SQLite table for my app. When I wanted to implement search functionality to my app, I found that the [Searchable Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) example uses a FTS3 virtual table. I've never work with FTS3 and I just want to know what the differences are. When they say that FTS3 "does not support column constraints and thus, cannot declare a primary key," does that mean I can't make a column a type (ie. text, integer, etc.)? How do I specify unique identifiers (id)? Should I manage/organize the data differently from an ordinary table? Is it meant to replace my original table if I want to implement search functionality with FTS3?

Comment: I was looking into this very same thing and found this blog post that might answer some of your questions: http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/ Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This article definitely has some useful information that is directed for the Android environment.